# How to make SSH tunnel as daemon?

Tags: ssh-tunneling, daemon

Actually, I need a secured VPN, but configuring it was too hard for me. So I decided to use SSH tunnel. The tunnel could be established when I logged in. :(

(1) How can I make a SSH tunnel without login? Like daemons. And (2) how can I keep the tunnel connections reliably?

I'm using `Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS`.

Comment: try the -N flag from ssh. https://superuser.com/a/1700730

Answer (score 5):

1. If the server allows public key authentication, put the public key of the connecting client to the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Use `ssh-keygen` on the client, the create a key pair. You may also use the `ssh-copy-id` script to copy the public key to the server. On key generation, you may omit the passphrase, so you won't be asked for it. Be sure to keep the private key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) safe.
2. Use [autossh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/autossh.1.html) to keep the tunnel alive.